# Shadows wont work properly for this THREE.js project

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

can anyone tell me if i messed up the model or the code in THREE:

[image]

the shadows are supposed to show up inside that cube but they're not working as intended

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please take this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Please provide your own efforts into solving the problem in terms of code, a.k.a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.